# CSS folder not found on IIS .net core wwwroot

Tags: c#, vue.js, asp.net-core, iis-10

Somehow I decided to build my web API and client separately after several hours failed to combine .net core 2.2 with vue+vuetify.

I build the client using Vue CLI, with this config:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? '/joblist/' : '/',
}
```

Then place the content of `dist` folder to `wwwroot` folder on .net core project, I use below code to enable `UseStaticFiles`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseDefaultFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Everything looks perfect when I debug with **APP URL** set to `http://localhost:49602/joblist`. But somehow when I publish to my Server, which is `myserver/joblist`, the server can't serve **EVERYTHING** placed inside `wwwroot/css` folder, so the site looks ugly.

At first, I thought the problem is the wwwroot path or something like that, but I can browse to `wwwroot/js` folder perfectly, so I try to rename `wwwroot/css` folder to `wwwroot/notcss`, the site works perfectly this time.

Can anybody help me with this problem?

**UPDATE:**

- The `wwwroot/css` and `wwwroot/js` is **perfectly exist** on the server.
- I **can** open any file inside `wwwroot/js` folder but **can not** open any
  file inside `wwwroot/css` folder.
- For now, I use a workaround by creating a hard link named `wwwroot/notcss` (can be any) then replace any `/css/*` reference in `index.html` file to `/notcss/*`

**UPDATE 2**

Here is the error I received on the browser when browse on one of any file in CSS folder

> **HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found**
>
> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
>
> **Detailed Error Information:**
>
> ```
> Module           IIS Web Core
> Notification     MapRequestHandler
> Handler          StaticFile
> Error Code       0x80070002
> Requested URL    http://localhost:80/joblist/css/app.14044b2f.css
> Physical Path    C:\inetpub\wwwroot\joblist\css\app.14044b2f.css
> Logon Method     Anonymous
> Logon User       Anonymous
> ```

Comment: What does the browser get as a response when requesting a file in `wwwroot/css`?

Comment: `404 - File or directory not found.`

Comment: Try enabling directory listing and see what you get when you request `{your web site base path}/css`

Comment: same, `404 - File or directory not found.`

Comment: Is the `css` folder actually created on the server? What if you directory-list `{your web site base path}/js`?

Comment: yes, `ccs` folder is exist on the server, but I can not open ANY file placed inside css folder, even though I can open ANY file placed on ANY folder beside `css` folder

Comment: Wich version of Vue CLI ? 2 or 3 ?

Comment: Does this repro without using IIS?

Comment: No, actually maybe the problem is IIS on my server, because when I debug it using VS, it ran without any problem, even though VS it self is using IIS Express as far as I know.

Comment: @anand_v.singh do you read my question?

Comment: You said the problem is in your IIS server probably, since it is working properly on IIS express in a comment above, thus the comment, a common problem when IIS express works and IIS doesn't is you don't have all features activated that are required, have seen that quite a few times, but doesn't look like you are looking for that advice, hence I am happily deleting that comment.

Comment: @anand_v.singh if Static File is not enabled in my server, then I will not be able to browse to `wwwroot/js` folder, as stated in my question above. I will repeat my probrem, I (ONLY) can not browse `wwwroot/css` folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There must be any some misscongured config, try to browse to `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config` on your server, looks for a file named `applicationHost.config` open the file then search for `css` text. if you see some suspicious config just delete it, don't forget to backup it first.

Comment: I decided to look at the file you meant, and yes there is some config for 'wwwroot/css' folder, I delete it then everything is normal after it. thanks